# How to program such a list in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, controls, settings

I would like to write a settings view for an OS X application and am looking for something like in the Xcode project settings:

[image]

How is such a control / list (containing disclosure buttons and settings) called, and were can I find a tutorial on it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK found it, it's an NSOutlineView.